# foreign key not getting copied to level 4 + jpa + hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My Entity level is like this

Level One

```
@Entity
public class LevelOne {
@Id
private long levelOnePK;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "levelOne")
private Set<LevelTwo> levelTwo;   


//getters setters omitted 
}
```

Level Two

```
@Entity
public class LevelTwo {

@Id
private long levelTwoPK;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "levelOnePK")
private LevelOne levelOne;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "levelTwo")
private Set<LevelThree> levelThree;

//getters setters omitted
}
```

Level Three

```
@Entity
public class LevelThree {

@Id
private long levelThreePK;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "levelOnePK")
@JoinColumn(name = "levelTwoPK")
private LevelTwo levelTwo;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "levelThree")
private Set<LevelFour> levelFour;

//getters setters omitted
}
```

Level Four  // Not working. Why ??

```
@Entity
public class LevelFour {

@Id
private long levelFourPK;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "levelOnePK")
@JoinColumn(name = "levelTwoPK")
@JoinColumn(name = "levelThreePK")
private levelThree levelThree;



//getters setters omitted
}
```

For the fourth level the error is "It is not mapped to a single entity"

It works upto level 3 and does not at level 4. I want the primary / foreign key of every level go down to the level below.  I am joining using all the primary keys from the above tables but it does not work.

It works if i join only if I do the below in Level 4. But i want keys from above level as well.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "levelThreePK")
private levelThree levelThree;
```

Comment: You do realize that `@OneToMany` must map to a collection? i.e. `@OneToMany Set<LevelFour> levelFours;`

Comment: There was a typo in my question. Level 4 was a set. . I rectified it now in my question.

Comment: I'd suggest you to create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.